# AutoIT how can i find real process name?

Tags: process, autoit

I want to detect some illegal programs with my AutoIT scripts. But if the cheater change illegal program's name, how can i find that?

What do i exactly check? Titlename, Class? or what?

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect if certain programs are running
You can check for:

> 1. Process name
> 2. Window Title name
> 3. Class
> 4. Control and text combinations

Yes, you will have to gather a lot of data for the programs you are after and their different versions, but it will give you a great detection rate.